# How to add a Content Picker field to orchard ContentType?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

Suppose I have a `ContentType` called Product. I wanna have a field called `RelatedProducts` in my custom type(e.g:Product) so that in admin panel, when user is editing (or adding a new product) a `ContentPicker` button displayed for user and user clicks on that button and a list of product appears, that gives user ability of selecting contents of type product.

Is there any implemented module in orchard for accomplishing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `ContentPicker` field is exactly what you're looking for. Enable ContentPicker module (if it's not enabled already), add Content Picker Field to your content type and you're set.

The Content Picker module is available starting from Orchard 1.5.

Comment: thanks for your response.is a way to extent to selecting more than one?

Comment: Hi, how do you select more than one?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but there should be an option for that within field settings (the same screen where you added the field to your Content Type).